# My sidebar is not visible on click of button

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, sidebar

I have made the right sidebar on click of button it appear but somehow the dialog box doesn't appear on click of the button

```css
    .modal.left .modal-dialog,
    .modal.right .modal-dialog {
      position: fixed;
      margin: auto;
      width: 320px;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    }

    .modal.left .modal-content,
    .modal.right .modal-content {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .modal.left .modal-body,
    .modal.right .modal-body {
      padding: 15px 15px 80px;
    }

    /*Left*/
    .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
      left: -320px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
      left: 0;
    }
          
    /*Right*/
    .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
      right: -320px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
      right: 0;
    }

    /* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
    .modal-content {
      border-radius: 0;
      border: none;
    }

    .modal-header {
      border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                                                    Right Sidebar Modal
                                                </button>
                                                <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                            
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                            
                                                        </div><!-- modal-content -->
                                                    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
                                                </div><!-- modal -->
                                                
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have added some css and some html structure
on click of the modal should open from the right but it disappeared , on click it doesnt shows .
I have added some css and some html structure
on click of the modal should open from the right but it disappeared , on click it doesnt shows .
I have added some css and some html structure
on click of the modal should open from the right but it disappeared , on click it doesnt shows .
I have added some css and some html structure
on click of the modal should open from the right but it disappeared , on click it doesnt shows .

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Class` target `.modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog` to `.modal-open .modal.right .modal-dialog`

```
.modal-open .modal.right .modal-dialog {
      right: 0;
    }
```

OR

change `class` name `in` to `show`

```
.modal.right.fade.show .modal-dialog {
      right: 0;
    }
```

```css
.modal.left .modal-dialog,
    .modal.right .modal-dialog {
      position: fixed;
      margin: auto;
      width: 320px;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    }

    .modal.left .modal-content,
    .modal.right .modal-content {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .modal.left .modal-body,
    .modal.right .modal-body {
      padding: 15px 15px 80px;
    }

    /*Left*/
    .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
      left: -320px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .modal-open .modal.left .modal-dialog{
      left: 0;
    }
          
    /*Right*/
    .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
      right: -320px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .modal-open .modal.right .modal-dialog {
      right: 0;
    }

    /* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
    .modal-content {
      border-radius: 0;
      border: none;
    }

    .modal-header {
      border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                                                    Right Sidebar Modal
                                                </button>
                                                <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                            
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                            
                                                        </div><!-- modal-content -->
                                                    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
                                                </div><!-- modal -->
                                                
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can i have some transition with animation too when it opens

Answer (score 0):

.modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog { right: 0;} its change to this type working fine

```
     .modal-open .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {right: 0}
```

```css
      .modal-open .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {right: 0}

    .modal.left .modal-dialog,
    .modal.right .modal-dialog {
      position: fixed;
      margin: auto;
      width: 320px;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    }

    .modal.left .modal-content,
    .modal.right .modal-content {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .modal.left .modal-body,
    .modal.right .modal-body {
      padding: 15px 15px 80px;
    }

    /*Left*/
    .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
      left: -320px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
      left: 0;
    }
          
    /*Right*/
    .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
      right: -320px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
      right: 0;
    }

    /* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
    .modal-content {
      border-radius: 0;
      border: none;
    }

    .modal-header {
      border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                                                    Right Sidebar Modal
                                                </button>
                                                <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                            
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                            
                                                        </div><!-- modal-content -->
                                                    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
                                                </div><!-- modal -->
                                                
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Supriya CS can i have some transition with animation too when it opens